# how to update 1 of multiple auxilliary routes in Angular app

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create an Angular (2+) app with four named `router-outlet`s. I come from an AngularJS (1) + ui-router background. In general, I have a top navbar, main content area, sidebar, and footer. I have no need for an unnamed outlet (but wouldn't mind getting the unnamed outlet to work for "content", so that routes default to there).

I have the following routes defined.

```
//  {
//    path: '',
//    pathMatch: 'full',
//    redirectTo: 'main'
//  },
//  {
//    path: 'main',
//    component: AppContentComponent
//  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    outlet: 'content',
    component: DefaultContentComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'video',
    outlet: 'sidebar',
    component: VideoComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'upNext',
    outlet: 'footer',
    component: UpNextTickerComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'navMenu',
    outlet: 'navbar',
    component: NavMenuComponent
  }
```

Which map to this template

```
<div class="navbar"><router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet></div>
<div class="content"><router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet></div>
<div class="sidebar"><router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet></div>
<div class="footer"><router-outlet name="footer"></router-outlet></div>
```

Since I have no "default" route, I use OnInit to initialize my routes

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
      private router: Router,
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    // initialize child views
    this.router.navigate([{
      outlets: {
        'content': ['home'],
        'sidebar': ['video'],
        'navbar':  ['navMenu'],
        'footer':  ['upNext'],
      }
    }]);
  }
}
```

So far, this all works. I end up at `localhost:4200/(content:home//sidebar:video//navbar:navMenu//footer:upNext)`.

I'm struggling to understand how to, say, have a navbar button change the sidebar outlet *only*. That is, how do I send a link to only one auxilliary route and leave the others as is? If I don't specify a path to `navigate`, it appends to what's there (It only works OnInit because what's there is `/`.). If I do specify a path, only the outlets I specify end up with content after the route change (the rest are set to `null`).

I don't want to have to specify every outlet every time. I think I could probably write a method that will copy existing routes if they aren't given, but that seems like it should be a last resort.

Comment: try something like this `router.navigate([{outlets: {sidebar: 'somepath'}], {relativeTo: this.route})`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got it to work, but it still requires a method call, which means injecting the service. Is there an alternative that doesn't?

Comment: what do you mean by `method call`, can you clarify?

Comment: I have to write a service and inject `Router` to use `router.navigate`, then inject that service into each component whose view needs to call the method. I'm hoping for an Angular built-in, like `[routerLink]`, that can handle this.

Comment: it can be done the same way using `routerLink`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45064308/2545680) below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to reconsider the approach here. It may be easier to just do something more like this:

```
<div class="navbar"><navbar ></navbar></div>
<div class="content"><router-outlet ></router-outlet></div>
<div class="sidebar"><sidebar></sidebar></div>
<div class="footer"><footer></footer></div>
```

Then you only have one router outlet. The other components are nested here. If there also needs to be routing within the sidebar, it could leverage child routes instead of named routes.

Comment: Yes, that's the conclusion I'm coming to. Though, I'm going to try to get `sidebar` to work as an auxiliary, so I don't have to toggle components on and off with `ngIf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use imperative navigation with the help of the `router`, you can do it like this:

```
router.navigate([{outlets: {sidebar: 'somepath'}], {relativeTo: this.route})
```

If you want to use `routerLink` directive you can do it like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {sidebar: 'somepath'}]">
```

You don't need to specify `{relativeTo: this.route}` because each link knows what route it is relative to.

Comment: Using `[routerLink]`, I end up with a URL like `http://localhost:4200/path;sidebar=video`, which doesn't work.

Comment: can you create a plunker? If it works with `router.navigate` it should work `routerLink` as well since the latter under the hood using `router.navigate`